# Outlook 2007 Add in not loading in outlook on xp

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I have developed an **Outlook 2007 Add-in** using Visual Studio 2010 (on Windows 7 64 bit Machine). Following is the properties window of my project:
[image]

This is working fine on all Windows 7 Machines, even if any machine does not have **.net framework client** then this is installed by setup & work correctly.

But now when I tried to install it on **Windows XP (32 bit)** machine, it installed successfully, also all registries were created as they are creating on other systems. But the Add-in is listed under **Inactive Application Addins** section on **Trust Center -> Addins**.

[image]

When I checked the COM Addins, I found following error:

```
Not Loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.
```

[image]

Then I selected **x86** as **Plateform target** & build the setup but still the same output. I also installed full **.net framework** on that machine but no success at all.

**EDIT 1:** I performed following steps for debugging, but no success:

1) I have set the **VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0** to display alert message for any exception, but no message was displayed. as mentioned in following blog: [Link to blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/haahmadi/2010/05/26/my-office-addin-does-not-load/). Note: there were alert messages for other previously Add-in(s) but not for mine.

2) I have Manually installed **.NET Framework 3.5**, **.NET Framework 4.0**, **VSTO 3 Runtime**, **VSTO 4 Runtime**.

3) I tried to write log file in my Add-in code, but that only worked on my development machine & not on windows XP machine. As that never triggered.

**EDIT 2:** I also installed Visual Studio on XP machine & created a new Outlook 2007 Addin project. When I ran the project it opened the outlook like on my development machine, but my Addin is listed in **InActive Applications Addins** section. No success.

I also tried to uninstall **.net framework 4.0 & 3.5** & then installed **.net framework 3.5**, after that I also installed **.net framework 3.5 sp1**, as this was suggested in some posts, then installed my Addin Setup, that Installed .net client 4.0. But still the same result.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to debug your addin on that machine to see what that run-time error us.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko What are the ways of debugging in such a case, my code is located in another machine. And setup was installed successfully, also it is working fine on other systems. Any Ideas in which event I need to put log message?

Comment: visual studio is installed on windows 7 machine and i dont have visual studio setup to install on windows xp. is there i can do some error logging so that i can get to know about the error when i run the add in on windows xp outlook 2007.

Comment: If you can't install VS, try to add try/catch blocks everywhere in your code and log the errors. Or comment out most of your code and bring it back a few lines at a time until problem comes back.

Comment: I have done all this. You can read my edit. I have even created a new extension which just displays a label but still that same error. Log file does not get created as log file will be created once the addin runs. Not Loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.

Comment: You should be able to install VS 2010 on Windows XP.

Comment: Check my Edit 1 and EDit 2